# Loading Python plugins on QGIS

Tags: qgis, windows, qgis-plugins

I've been having problems loading several QGIS plugins. I've just done a reinstall of QGIS 1.7.4., followed all the instructions, so just did a default installation (I've tried the osgeo4w installer already and it only made matters worse...).

Whenever I try to use, let's say the "1 band raster color table" plugin, I get error messages. First of all, when I load the plugin, I get the message "Cannot continue. Problems!". If I close this message, the plugin stays open anyway and let's me select the options I want. When I click "Create", I get yet another error message, that starts off with this:

```
"Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Tiago/.qgis/python/plugins\bcccoltbl1\bcctbl.py", line 826, in applyTBL
    myStats = self.myGRD.getStats()
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'getStats'"
```

Now, I've been told that this might have to do with me having non-Latin characters in the path... I've been trying to understand this, but I'm getting really confused... When I used QGIS 1.6, I had no problems of this sort. But I didn't change a thing in my disk's organization when I upgraded to QGIS 1.7.

How can this be, that the plugins ran smoothly before but not anymore?

If I had non-latin characters, they would be there before, anyway, so the plugins should have had these same errors.

Comment: please provide full path to the raster, where is your raster located and what its filename.

Comment: Not an answer I'm afraid. I've just tested the "1 band raster color table" plug-in and I get exactly the same problem as you. QGIS 1.7.4, 32-bit Vista. I don't have non-Latin characters in my path names or file names so I don't think this is to do with font encoding.

Comment: Curiously, After going through the whole shennanigans of uninstalling the OSGEO4W software and re-installing the standalone version of QGIS 1.7.4. (as well as all the plugins), it suddenly started to work... Let's see if it will actually continue like this!

Comment: nhopton, sorry for not getting back at this earlier, but I ended up not working that much on those projects lately. It stills is a problem, though - sometimes it simply won't work, sometimes it does. Total mistery for me!