# Installing 1-band color raster color table?

Tags: qgis, raster, colortable

I would like to use the "1-band raster colour table" extension.
I'm using QGIS Wroclaw 1.7.4.

In the plugin installer I can't find this extension, even I quote for third party extensions thing. Does anybody know its name in the Plugin manager? Is there another plugin similar to 1-band raster that I could use?

I've read on another forum that this extension don't work on QGIS 1.7.... is that right?

bccaddRcolor: seems to be a similar extension than 1-band raster, but i work only on QGIS 1.8.

Where can I download it ?

Answer (score 5):

I am using QGIS 1.8 Lisboa so I do not know if the "1-band raster colour table" plugin works on 1.7.4 (I did not use it on 1.7), but you can try this on 1.7.4 and see what happens. The plugin repository needs to be added first (this may be why you cannot find it).

To add it:
1. on the QGIS Toolbar go to Plugins --> Fetch Python Plugins... 
2. add a new repository. In the Repositories tab click the Add button and enter:
   Name: BC Consulting repository 
   URL:  http://www.bc-consult.com/free/plugins.xml 
3. click OK 
4. go to Plugins tab and install the "1-Band Raster Colour Table v1.x"

Check out the BC Consulting website for more on how to use the  [1-band raster colour table](http://www.bc-consult.com/free/bcccoltbl1.html).

Check out this [osgeo qgis notice of plugin reorganization](http://osgeo-org.1560.n6.nabble.com/Notice-of-plugins-reorganisation-BC-Consulting-plugins-td4883879.html) for more info on where and why the plugin is difficult to find.

You also might want to try the "One-band raster to paletted or RGB raster" plugin. For me, these two plugins now show up in the Raster dropdown menu on the QGIS Toolbar (on 1.8).

Edit: The BC Consulting webpage says that this works with 1.6 and above, so it should work with 1.7.4.

Comment: BC Consulting's website is down.

Comment: True, but this thread is from 2012. I doubt very many people in 2021 are using QGIS 1.7. The already old stable version 2.18 is far superior to 1.7, and runs on machines with older operating systems and fewer resources.

Comment: And was it you who down voted an answer from 2012?

Answer (score 4):

You may be referring to the [bcccoltbl1 plugin, also by BC Consulting](http://www.bc-consult.com/freebies.htm). For some reason, it is not available in any repository via the Plugin Installer.

Comment: BC Consulting's website is down.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to Rudi's answer, I could also find this in the contributed repository

- Plugins -> Fetch Python Plugins
- Switch to Repository tab and click Add
- Add 'QGIS Contributed' as name and 'http://pyqgis.org/repo/contributed' as URL
- In Options tab, select 'Show all plugins, even those marked experimental'
- Now you search for 'band' and you'll see the plugin in the results.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can get some information [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/22777/trouble-with-python-plugins-on-qgis) about Trouble with Python plugins on QGIS. Solving this frustrating problem, this is the solution of @TTome as classic windows problem which recover after restarting. :)

> Curiously, After going through the whole shennanigans of uninstalling
>   the OSGEO4W software and re-installing the standalone version of QGIS
>   1.7.4. (as well as all the plugins), it suddenly started to work... Let's see if it will actually continue like this!

i hope it helps you...

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually I have no error message as I can't even find the plugin.