# Where can I find the 1-band color raster plugin for QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to install “1-band color raster color table”?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/25361/how-to-install-1-band-color-raster-color-table)

I'm searching for the 1-band color raster plugin. What is the essential repository? Or is there another tool for creating raster maps?